# Jquery scripts won't fully load with Jquery hide

Tags: jquery, click, loading, show-hide

I've downloaded a jQuery galleryscript. I made a page with thumbnail images, wenn you click on a thumbnail, it is supposed to load the gallery div `#galleria`. I have set the gallery `#galleria` div to hide in the jquery script so i'm able to call it when i want too. This the example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Load fullscreen theme
    Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/fullscreen/galleria.fullscreen.min.js');

    // Intialize Galleria
    $('#galleria').galleria()

    $('#galleria').hide();

    $('.open').click(function() {
        $('#galleria').toggle(1);
    });

});
```

What i think seems to be the problem is that i hide the div to quickly, the scripts might not have time to load? Because when i set a delay on the `$('#galleria').hide();` like this `$('#galleria').hide(1000);` it does work but its ugly because u can see it flickering.

I'm not even sure i have called the correct error. So can anyone tell me how i can hide the div when the page loads and call it when i click on a thumbnail. So i wont have to use an ugly delay and without a delay the script will work.

Here are the pages with both examples. U are able to toggle the `#galleria`div with the black button on the bottom of the screen.

Page without a delay: http://fabianvanderwulp.nl/Test2/3d_visualizations.html

Page with a delay: http://fabianvanderwulp.nl/Test/3d_visualizations.html

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can start that galleria div with style='display:none'.
2. For whatever reason, the error showing is that the dimensions for the galleria div is too small 50px x 50px. So, work on that and you should be fine .. I think.

Good luck!

```
===
   <div class="footer"><p>© 2009 - 2011 Kontravision</p></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>  
<div id="galleria">      <====== style='display:none'
===
```

Comment: Thx alot, giving the #galleria div a width and height and adding 'display:none' did the trick